Proving a property of an antisymmetric tensor $\textbf{T}$, where $\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{T} \cdot \textbf{a}=0$.
I would like to prove that $\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{T} \cdot \textbf{a}=0$, where $\textbf{T}$ is a second order antisymmetric tensor and $\textbf{a}$ is a vector.
I know I can prove this by proving that $\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{T} \cdot \textbf{a} = -\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{T} \cdot \textbf{a}$, but I got stuck as I think my reasoning is wrong.
My method was the following:
Since $\textbf{T}$ is antisymmetric, we have that $T_{ij}=-T_{ji}$.
Now, $\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{T} \cdot \textbf{a} = a_{i}T_{ij}a_{j}=-a_{i}(-T_{ij})a_{j}=-a_{i}T_{ji}a_{j}$. Note the last step of this line was using the fact that $T_{ij}=-T_{ji}$. Therefore, $\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{T} \cdot \textbf{a}=-a_{i}T_{ji}a_{j}$. This is where I get stuck, since $-a_{i}T_{ji}a_{j}\neq -\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{T} \cdot \textbf{a}$, since the dot product is a contraction  between adjacent indicies of different tensors and/or vectors.
Where have I gone wrong and what could I do? I've been tring to figure this out for almost 6 hours now with different approaches but all have sort of led to this issue.
Thanks!

"same adjacent indices" is not a thing. Also, you are free to change the order of the tensors in the product which means $a_iT_{ji}a_j=T_{ji}a_ia_j$. Likewise, $T_{ji}a_ia_j=T_{ji}a_ja_i$. And you are also are free to rename indices as long as you make one change at a time and not to an index that is already taken. Here you can let $i\to r$ and $j\to s$ and then back in reverse order to get $T_{ij}a_ia_j=-T_{ji}a_ia_j=-T_{ij}a_ia_j$, or $2T_{ij}a_ia_j=0$

Thanks for your response ContraKinta!
I made an error in my question - I should have written "since the dot product is a contraction  between adjacent indicies of different tensors and/or vectors". This is is how my lecturer defined the dot product "$\cdot$" for us. For example, $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{B}=a_{i}B_{ij}$. Using this definition, like how I did in my question, a dot product on either side of the 2nd order tensor would be, $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{B}\cdot\textbf{a}$ would then be $a_{i}B_{ij}a_{j}$.

This leads me to think that the first and third sides of the equation you gave, $T_{ij}a_ia_j=-T_{ji}a_ia_j=-T_{ij}a_ia_j$, don't imply a dot product , as the contractions don't occur between adjacent indicies. I feel like I could be completely wrong, but something doesn't add up!
Also I feel like that second equality sign isn't true at all, i.e. $T_{ji}a_ia_j\neq-T_{ij}a_ia_j$, as this completely violates the antisymmetric property of T ($T_{ij}=-T_{ji}$).

One last thing, is $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{B}\cdot\textbf{a}=\textbf{a}\cdot(\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{B})=(\textbf{B}\cdot\textbf{a})\cdot\textbf{a}$ a true statement?
Any more thoughts?

Using your notation ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf T} \cdot {\bf a}=a_iT_{ij}a_j$. Since $i,j$ are dummy indices you could also write $a_jT_{ji}a_i$. Using the antisymmetric property you have $a_jT_{ji}a_i=-a_jT_{ij}a_i=-a_iT_{ij}a_j$. So $a_iT_{ij}a_j=a_jT_{ji}a_i=-a_iT_{ij}a_j$. This means that $2a_iT_{ij}a_j=0$.

Thank you @TedBlack, this makes a lot of sense. I didn't know we could just switch the $a_{j}$ and the $a_{i}$ around like you did on the LHS of the series of equalities ($a_jT_{ji}a_i=-a_jT_{ij}a_i=-a_iT_{ij}a_j$) you provided!

In tensor notation, the contraction is defined by the indices, not the placing of the terms. For instance $U_{ij}b_ia_j =\mathbf{ b}\cdot U \cdot {a}$. In matrix notation this is $\mathbf{b}^T U \mathbf{a}$ and in your notation this is $\mathbf{b}\cdot U \cdot \mathbf{a}$. The tensor $R_{ij}a_ia_j$, which is the outer product of the vector a is by definition symmetric.

$R_{ij}=a_ia_j$ even. And the contraction of two indices between a symmetric tensor and an asymmetric tensor is always null. $R_{ij}T_{ij}=1/2(R_{ij}T_{ij}-R_{ij}T_{ji})=1/2(R_{ij}T_{ij}-R_{ij}T_{ij})=0$

@ContraKinta this makes perfect sense now. Thanks for taking to time to explain this!
